# Jest Mock not working in basic example of exported function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a simple example function, let's call it like this:

```
const otherFunction = () => {..........}

const someFunctionImTesting = async () => {
  const result = await otherFunction(param);
```

and both are in the same file exported bellow like:

```
export {
  otherFunction,
  someFunctionImTesting
};
```

In the test file I'm doing:

```
import { 
  otherFunction,
  someFunctionImTesting
} from '../service';

jest.mock('../service', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../service'),
  otherFunction: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('testing', () => {
  it('........', async () => {
    await someFunctionImTesting();
    expect(otherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And `expect(otherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();` is always 0 even I can see that method should be called.

I think I've done this a million times already, but what am I doing wrong?

I tried changing how `otherFunction` is mocked, but I'm always getting the same result.